# AngularFire / Firebase - How Do You Delete Key That is More Than One Level Deep?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have an synced object that is initialized like this:

```
var sync = $firebase(ref);
var syncObject = sync.$asObject();
syncObject.$bindTo($scope, 'data');
```

The synced object has the following structure:

```
{
    levelone: {
        leveltwo: {
            valueone: 1
            valuetwo: 2
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to remove one of the values with `$remove()`, but I am not able to delete anything other than the entire object with this method.

The following will delete the entire object:

```
syncObject.$remove('levelone.leveltwo.valueone');
```

I do not want to use `$save()` to overwrite the entire synced object.

Is there anyway to remove a nested key with `$remove()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to drill through multiple layers with the `$remove()` function.  I ended up using vanilla Firebase JS library methods to do the delete.

```
var ref = new Firebase(myFirebaseURL);
// The child() method (from the vanilla JS library) allows you to target keys 
// more than one level deep
ref.child('levelone/leveltwo/valueone').remove();
var sync = $firebase(ref);
```

You can chain the `child()` function off of the original JS Firebase class object and then run the `remove()` method off of that (notice that this is the `remove()` method and not the `$remove()` method).